# writing a stateless .net web api to work with a node web server

Tags: asp.net, node.js, api, authentication

We currently have a node web server that does authentication of users including oauth2 to google and facebook. We would like for it to handle the serving of web pages while a stateless .NET web api handles the serving of the actual data (which is all requested asynchronously). My question is how to handle authentication to the web api?

I mean should the client even authenticate to the api (and if so how do we do the pass through authentication so that it is authenticated to both once authenticating against the web server) or should the web server authenticate the user and then just forward all api requests to the api along with a user id? What is the standard scheme used for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is late, but I'll post my thoughts for the heck of it.  I would place a dummy api in your node app, just a simple pass-through for everything that is in your data api (the .net one).  Then I'd lock down the data api so only your node server can talk to it.  The short answer is that any api that you expose to the internet has to be locked down.  If you do the above, you don't have to expose your data api to the internet.  You get the added benefit of not having to deal with CORS - you can have a simple /api folder hanging off of your domain.  You can also use this pass-through api to aggregate calls to multiple business apis if your solution ever grows.  It's a very scalable architecture.

If you don't want to do the above, then you'll need to either place the data api on the same domain as the other site, or setup CORS so javascript/AJAX from one can call into the other.  Once your data api can see cookies written by the other site, you'll need to authenticate them, probably very manually, in your .net api, since .net didn't write the auth cookie - node did.